# form for adding or editing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to display a form to add or edit the result if it exists. I have a table of n * n, where n number of teams in the cell is given by the result. How best does this?

```
view/championship/show.erb
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr><th>&nbsp;</th>
    <% @teams.each do |teamhome| %>
    <th class="vertical"><%= teamhome.name %></th>
    <% end %>    
  </tr>
  <% @teams.each do |teamguest| %>
  <tr>
    <th><%= teamguest.name %></th>
    <% @teams.each do |teamhome| %>
      <%if teamhome == teamguest %>
        <td bgcolor = '#F9F9F9'>
      <% else %>
        <td> 

         #render form               


        </td>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

models

```
class Score < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :team1_score, :team2_score, :team1_id, :team2_id, :team1, :team2

  belongs_to :team1, class_name: 'Team', foreign_key: :team1_id
  belongs_to :team2, class_name: 'Team', foreign_key: :team2_id

  def self.to_arr

    score_arr = self.find(:all, :select => 'team1_id, team2_id, team1_score, team2_score').to_a

  end


end


class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  belongs_to :championship
  has_many :team1_scores, class_name: 'Score', foreign_key: :team1_id
  has_many :team2_scores, class_name: 'Score', foreign_key: :team2_id

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 100 }
  validates :championship_id, presence: true


end
```

schema

"team1_id"|"team2_id"|"team1_score"|"team2_score"

Comment: It's not clear what your question is.  Are you having a problem with this code, or are you looking for confirmation that it is the proper approach?

Comment: I have problem with this code. I want to display a table of forms in each cell for create scores or editing scores if the score is already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to load all your scores as a hash in the form `{ [:team1_id, :team2_id] => [:team1_score, :team2_score] }`:

```
@scores = Score.all.inject({}) do |m, s| 
  m[[s.team1_id, s.team2_id]] = [s.team1_score, s.team2_score]
  m
end
```

Now you can render the scores for each home/guest pairing like this:

```
<% scores = @scores[[teamhome.id, teamguest.id]] %>
<%= "#{scores.first} / #{scores.last}" if scores %>
```

The advantage to this approach is that you can find the matching score by hash key, which should be fairly quick even for large amounts of data.  The downside is that this hash is loading for *all* scores - even those not included in the `@championship`.  You can build a scope to narrow the scores to the relevant teams if you want to avoid this problem.  Then just call `Score.your_scope` instead of `Score.all`.

An alternative approach (that doesn't require building a hash) would be to get the scores directly from the home team and detect the appropriate match for that guest team cell:

```
<% scores = teamhome.team1_scores.detect{|s| s.team2_id == teamgues.id }
<%= "#{scores.team1_score} / #{scores.team2_score}" if scores %>
```

If you don't have an overly large amount of data, this simpler approach should suffice.  Just make sure to eager load the home team scores when you load the teams initially, or your performance will suffer from N+1 queries.

**UPDATE**

In both these approaches, the score was rendered as `"home_team_score / guest_team_score"`, but only if a matching score was found.  If not found, then nothing is rendered - this is due to the `if scores` conditional statement.  If you want to render something else, you can change the conditional to use the ternary operator.  The example below follows the second approach for collecting the scores:

```
<%= scores ? "#{scores.team1_score} / #{scores.team2_score}" : "No Score" %>
```

This will render `'No Score'` if a matching set of scores was not found.

Comment: I need render form for create if score of  match is empty, and I need render form for edit score if score of match already created

Comment: @parliament: Updated to explain how you might do this.